# Good method to provide small additional voltage while on battery?

Tags: power, batteries, solenoid

I have a circuit that drives solenoid lock rated @ 9V as shown below. The circuit works when the power is connected to the wall, which gives a constant 9V DC to Solenoid Power V+.

[image]

I also have a battery backup circuit implemented that looks like the following. When the wallwart is disconnected, the power from battery kicks in. The problem is I'm using 6 x AA rechargeable batteries, giving about 7.2 voltage. This voltage is insufficient to drive the solenoid lock. What's a good way to provide that additional 1.8V I'm missing here?

[image]

Edit: The diodes I'm using are schottky diodes: 1N5818. So the forward voltage lost from the diodes are minimal

Comment: Can you provide a link to the datasheet for the solenoid you are using? Have you measured (ideally with a 'scope, rather than the averaging effect of a multimeter) the voltage across the solenoid coil when it is driven by the 7.2V (nominal) battery - so you can see what voltage is *really* available to the solenoid under load? If the battery is 7.2V, then it will be a lower voltage which actual reaches the solenoid under load (even ignoring the schottky diode Vf of D2). The question is, how much lower - and what are the actual requirements of the solenoid (hence the need for the datasheet).

Comment: Appropriate use of a *large* capacitor *might* help, depending on the info from those two questions.

Comment: Make the battery pack from three 3.7V rechargeable lithium ion cells?

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1512 This is the solenoid lock I'm using, but don't think there's a detailed datasheet for this. It just says 9V-12V can be applied. The voltage across the solenoid coil comes out to be 6.27V using a multimeter, when powered from batteries (Don't have scope, sorry)

Comment: Also, it's a worry that the Vce(sat) of the TIP102 is shown in a Fairchild (now OnSemi) datasheet at 2.0-2.5V - so you are likely losing a similar voltage from *any* power source you try to use. I would probably use a low Rds(on) MOSFET instead.

Comment: Thanks. What was the "no load" battery voltage, which resulted in the 6.27V voltage across the solenoid? (Shame about the lack of a scope - we can't trust that 6.27V is the lowest voltage :-( ) (Yes, I changed my question, when I read your info carefully about this being a battery test, sorry.)

Comment: 6.27V is with battery power. With 9V main power, it comes out to be 7.9V (don't know if this matters)

Comment: No load battery voltage is 7.2V (voltage of batteries with nothing connected), if I understood your question right. It's 6 x AA (NiMH) batteries

Comment: I'm surprised the battery voltage (without the solenoid being operated) was measured at exactly 7.2V, but that's all I need for now. Thanks.

Comment: I shouldn't have started trying to help just before bedtime, but anyway... Two more measurements: Please operate the solenoid from the battery, but instead of measuring the voltage across the solenoid as before, please measure (a) between the "Solenoid V+" and the "Solenoid V-" on your diagram, near to the solenoid, and then (b) once more, operate the solenoid and measure the battery voltage near to (or immediately across) the battery. I *think* those various measurements will allow us to see where the various voltage drops are happening (e.g. battery due to internal R, wiring and Vce).

Comment: @SamGibson Voltage between Solenoid V+ and Solenoid Ground when lock is operated from battery: 6.8V. Voltage immediately across battery when solenoid lock is active: 7.02V

Comment: Assuming that Vin is connected to SOLENOID Power V+, and that GND is connected to SOLENOID power GND, it seems to me that the most sensible solution for your problem would be to up the output voltage of your battery pack by adding more cells of the kind you're already using or to replace them with  fewer but higher voltage rechargeable lithium cells.  By the way, what's the 1k resistor for?

Comment: @EMFields Increasing the battery voltage is the last resort I'd like to go with, as it does drive up the cost. For the 1K resistor, I'm trying to recharge the batteries while it's on 9V wall power supply. For 2500mAH capacity batteries, I want the charge capacity to be at C/300 so I need a current of 8mA or less. The potential difference from wall power to batteries is 1.8V so I need a resistor of 225 ohms or greater. Since the circuit is not expected to go out of power often, I decided to be safe and choose 1K ohms to charge it as slowly as possible to avoid overcharging damages

Comment: @Xiagua - Thanks for collecting those measurements. They helped to confirm where the various voltage losses were. I've explained my approach in an answer, which I hope makes sense. I doubt that adding a beefy capacitor (at a battery voltage of 7.02 - 7.2V) would be enough for reliable solenoid operation - hence my suggestion of a boost converter / regulator. I hope I interpreted the data correctly, but it's very late here so I'm now offline. If you disagree with my maths, please leave a question and I'll look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few possible solutions, but [according to Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1512), that solenoid is not suited to 9V battery use, so it's not completely surprising that you are having problems at 7.2V :-( They say:

> You will need a fairly good power supply to drive a solenoid, as a lot of current will rush into the solenoid to charge up the electro-magnet, about 500mA, so don't try to power it with a 9V battery!

[...]

> - 12VDC (you can use 9-12 DC volts, but lower voltage results in weaker/slower operation)
> - Draws 650mA at 12V, 500 mA at 9V when activated

Based on the [TIP102 datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP102.pdf), for 500mA Ic (the current required at 9V according to Adafruit), then Vce(sat) is around 0.8V. Your measurements show it is a bit less at (6.8V - 6.27V =) 0.53V.

The higher datasheet values of Vce(sat) in the datasheet (2.0V - 2.5V) were for higher currents than you are using, before we had the info from the Adafruit page. Thankfully the Vce(sat) drop is not so large in your case, although a suitable MOSFET would still reduce the loss from 0.53V.

As you see, the battery voltage itself also drops from 7.2V to 7.02V due to its internal resistance.

Overall, instead of trying to "add voltage" just when the battery backup is being used, I suggest you to add a boost converter which is *always* used for the solenoid's supply, suitable for Vin = 9V (DC input from mains supply) or 7.2V (battery backup) (actually battery voltage under load is closer to 7V as you measured, and the boost converter actually needs to be suitable for whatever is the lowest battery voltage you think might happen in real life e.g. after long mains outage - 6V perhaps?) and Vout = 12V, rated for a minimum of 1A *and* add an output capacitor (e.g. 4700uF) to improve load regulation under step changes of load i.e. when the solenoid operates.

From the schematics supplied, I believe it could be fitted between the Vin from the second diagram (which can come from either the mains power DC input or from the battery via D2) and the Solenoid Power connections on the right of the first diagram.

An alternative, as *EM Fields* has kindly suggested, is to have a higher battery voltage, although I think that would complicate your (currently very simple) battery charging arrangement. FYI, trickle charging NiMH batteries is sometimes discouraged by manufacturers, especially with modern cells. I remember an answer by *Russell McMahon* perhaps 3-4 months ago, which went into the details - you might want to try to find that, as it was worth reading.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer. I guess my task is to find a boost converter that fits my profile nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The pull-in and drop-out voltages of a solenoid are often very different. This is because the geometry of the magnetic circuit changes between open and closed. If you can persuade your 9-12v solenoid to pull-in, then you may find it doesn't drop out until the voltage drops to 5, maybe 4 volts, or even less. This is an experiment that it's worth you doing.

If you find the battery pack you are using *is* capable of holding the solenoid once energised (and only if), then you could employ a very large capacitor to give a switch-on boost, like this ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO11vT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the solenoid is off, C1 charges to the rail voltage through R1 and R2. When you want to turn the solenoid on, turn on both Q1.

Q1 pulls the bottom end of C1 up to rail voltage, which sends its top end to 2x rail, which applies this through D1 to the output. The capacitor is sized to store enough charge to pull the solenoid in before it discharges fully. Once it has discharged, the solenoid is held in by D4.

Comment: So on a separate breadboard, I was able to pull the solenoid lock straight from the batteries (even with the forward voltage drop from the schottky diodes). Does this mean I could go ahead and use the above circuitry? What do you mean by turn on Q1 and Q2 by the way? I don't see a second transistor here

Comment: It would be nice to do the complete hold-in experiment, but if it will pull in from the batteries, it sounds OK. When I wrote the text, my diagram did have two transistors, until I realised that D4 could connect to Q1 and Q2 was not needed!

Comment: Surprisingly, the lock actually stops holding at 6V so I think I will give this a try. Many thanks for the suggestion